# Dealing with memory, when using std::vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-leaks, scoping

I'm using vector with my own class type:

```
std::vector<CItem> m_vItems;
```

In my class I'm initializing SFML types like texture and sprite:

```
class CItem
{
    (...)
    sf::Texture m_Texture;
    sf::Sprite m_Sprite;
    sf::IntRect* m_pRect;
    (...)
}
```

I'm trying to pass object to my vector declared as member of other class `CLevel` and I'm doing it inside method of that class like this:

```
CItem *temp = new CItem(x, y, kind);
m_vItems.push_back(*temp);
```

As you see, I'm not deleteing `temp` pointer with `delete`, but in destructor of class `CLevel` I've got a simple line:

```
std::vector<CItem>().swap(m_vItems);
```

And I'm little confused about memory leaks. Is my program has got some of these or the line above solving problem and my example has been correctly written?

Comment: please insert a code of destructor

Comment: Which destructor? CItem or CLevel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CItem *temp = new CItem(x, y, kind);
m_vItems.push_back(*temp); // here a copy of *temp is pushed into vector
```

You should call delete somewhere to delete what you allocated with temp:

```
delete temp;
```

to avoid memory leak. Any call to `new` must have matching call to `delete` somewhere. This doesn't influence a copy of temp that was pushed into vector. It still exist as long as vector exists.

The best is to use just:

```
m_vItems.push_back(CItem(x, y, kind)); // implement this constructor correctly
                                       // to avoid uninitialized variables
```

Always when leaks are concern you can profile your program with tool: Valgrind or Visual Leak Detector.

Answer (score 2):

Your program calls `new` without a matching `delete`, and it didn't pass the result of `new` to some other class that will manage it for you. Therefore your program has a memory leak.

Do you have a problem with using `m_vItems.push_back(CItem(x, y, kind));` instead of the two line example you gave?

Comment: When I'm using it like this, after method's end sprite's texture has got incorrect, random values of width and height.

Comment: implement this constructor correctly to avoid uninitialized variables

Answer (score 0):

if your are on Windows platform, you could use the CRT library to detect if you have any leaks in a specific code section. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains how to do it in VS 2012 it is also available for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to keep a vector of pointers, rather than a vector of CItems, I'd use a smart pointer to manage the object lifetime. A [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is easy to use:

```
shared_ptr<CItem*> temp(new CItem(x,y,z));
m_vItems.push_back(temp);
```

When the vector goes, the CItem will be cleaned up correctly. When the items are passed around, they will be handled correctly too - no memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

A memory leak is when space is allocated on the heap (in your case by calling new) and the reference to that memory is lost.  In other words, you have no way to reclaim the memory by calling delete.  If you use swap to move pointers from one vector to another then technically that's not a leak because you still have a reference to the memory in the other vector and you can still call delete.

Remember to call delete eventually.  It may be tempting in some cases depending on the use to just let the system cleanup later and not delete the memory ever, e.g. if the code is a CGI.  However, that can cause problems later on when the code is used in a use case not initially anticipated, e.g. a unit test that's called from a long-running framework.  It's generally worth the time to code the delete right away, even if doing so has no bearing on an immediate goal, rather than put yourself in the position where you might have to circle back and try to fix it later.